# Samsung Galaxy S3 phone - typing additional symbols

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

There are some symbols available when using the on screen keyboard on my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone, but I would like to access additional symbols, like percent sign and degree symbol.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Originally I had 3 pages of symbols, including the degree symbol. There was an "update" and it's gone. I use it a lot and miss it.

I just downloaded the [GO keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.emoji.gokeyboard) and it has a degree symbol °. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Samsung keyboard on my S3. I can tap the "123 Sym" key to reveal the symbols keyboard.  Then, tap the "1/2" key to reveal the second page of the symbols keyboard.  You should find what you want there.  The confusion may result from the "1/2" key.  It's not intuitive that there's a second page of symbols under that key.

Answer (score 0):

there is no degree sign on the second page.  It looks like there is 3 pages of symbols (123 Sym) but in fact there are only 2 pages..